# How to refresh tagbox and add selections in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropbox that works well, but I want to be able to override the User's selections using jquery.  My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2br68kjv/ shows the tagbox already displaying 'Rock and 'Paper'.  What I want is to replace the contents with 'Paper' and 'Scissors'.  My thinking was to clear the tagbox first, then add in the new selections.  In real life my list is very long and clearing everything in the tagbox first would save a lot of code.  But after clearing the tagbox using .val('') nothing seems to work. Any ideas much appreciated.

```
<select id="dropList" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
  <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
  <option value="Scissors">Scissors</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
<button name="button" id='buttoncode' value="OK" type="button">Click Me</button>



$("#dropList").select2();
$('#dropList').val(["Rock","Paper"]).trigger('change.select2');

$("#buttoncode").on("click", function()  {

$('#dropList').val('').trigger('change.select2');

var sel=$('#dropList').val();
sel.push("Paper");
sel.push("Scissors");
$('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');

})



select {
width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying you want to replace the first selection with a different selection while not changing the list of options? If so I did it by just setting the value again.

```
$("#buttoncode").on("click", function()  {
// overwrite selection
$('#dropList').val(["Paper", "Scissors"]).trigger('change.select2');
$('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');
})
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kygk7ef4/

Comment: Thanks.  Sometimes I can't see the wood for trees!